# UserCollection? Cant locate dll

Tags: c#

Ive added the using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

But still getting errors, is it some dll i need to download?

This is the error:

> The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Similar question, but not exactly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333855/sharepoint-how-to-add-a-reference-from-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590346/using-c-sharp-to-access-sharepoint-where-can-i-find-the-reference-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (are you missing an assembly reference?)

That's the important part.  You say you have added a `using` statement for the namespace, but have you added an assembly reference?

First, you need the DLL.  Next, right click your project's "References" section (Solution Explorer window), click "Add Reference" and then browse to the DLL.  Add it and you should be set to go.

Comment: Does that mean add a .dll to the References ? By right click and "Add reference"? If so i havent, i couldn't find it Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll in there

Comment: @user1213488: Yes.  You do not have access to their code until you add a reference to the assembly itself.  You need to find the correct DLL, simply adding a `using SomeNameSpace` is not sufficient (how could your project know where to find the code?)